# How do I create an image mask from a PNG with transparency in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, png

I need to create a Java class to create an image mask from a PNG image with transparency. I would prefer to do this as much as possible with out-of-the box image processing libraries as possible.

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Apparently he doesn't know of any 'out-of-the-box' classes to attempt using. It does help to get some more information. Does the PNG also contain color besides the mask? (like the dice on [wikipedia/PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics))

Answer (score 0):

- Read original image,
- Create a new image with a new raster and a new colormodel:

  - A raster that wraps the original data buffer of the image, just interpreted differently (using the colormodel),
  - A colormodel that takes the first byte out of every four and interprets it as intensity.

Original raster needs to be a byte-interleaved raster, with four bytes per pixel. No safety checks are in place in this example.

```
BufferedImage orig = ImageIO.read(new File("temp.png"));

DataBuffer dataBuffer = orig.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
ColorSpace cs         = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
int[]      nBits      = {8};
int[]      bOffs      = {0};
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits, false, false,
                                                Transparency.TRANSLUCENT,
                                                DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(dataBuffer,
                                                       orig.getWidth(), orig.getHeight(),
                                                       orig.getWidth() * 4, 4,
                                                       bOffs, null);

BufferedImage mask = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
```